# Route TTS output to bluetooth headset while phone is ringing

Tags: android, bluetooth, text-to-speech

I am having a EDR bluetooth headset and need to route TTS voice to headset. I can achieve it using the following code while not in call.

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.startBluetoothSco();
am.setBluetoothScoOn(status);
ttsMap.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL));
```

But I need to route the voice to bluetooth set while phone is ringing for my application [Caller Name Talker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pa.caller) and all I can hear is nothing but incoming call alert of bluetooth module. Is there any hack to route audio to bluetooth device while phone is ringing?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: what is your complete code in the following circumstances:
1) at the point when the program speaks out the text string (contact name)?, and
2) at the point when the program speaks out John Doe-the sample text string for testing voice under Voice Settings of your program?